# Updating plpgsql when upgrading Postgres on AWS RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm upgrading from Postgres 10.21 to 14.4 on an AWS RDS instance. The database is pretty vanilla and small. I haven't installed any custom extensions. (It might be possible that RDS installed something itself – I'm not sure.)

I'm doing a dry-run of the upgrade process before upgrading the production database. The upgrade seems to work correctly and I can connect and see the data after the upgrade.

However, the logs indicate a possible error or further action required, saying:

```
Your installation contains extensions that should be updated
with the ALTER EXTENSION command.  The file
    update_extensions.sql
when executed by psql by the database superuser will update
these extensions.
```

Prior to performing the upgrade, I checked that there weren't any unexpected extensions installed in the database using

```
SELECT * FROM pg_extension;
```

which verified that the only installed extension was `plpgsql` version 1.0. I checked that this was the latest version available on Postgres 14.4 on the [AWS extension version table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/PostgreSQLReleaseNotes/postgresql-extensions.html#postgresql-extensions-14x) and it says that 1.0 is the latest version.

I also checked the list of available versions on the upgraded instance using

```
SELECT * FROM pg_available_extension_versions where name = 'plpgsql';
```

which verified that plpgsql 1.0 is the only available version.

So, my questions are:

1. Why is this message being logged? How do I fix it?
2. Can I view the `update_extensions.sql` file on an AWS RDS instance?
3. Is there anything I actually need to do or is the upgrade OK?

Thanks very much for your help!

–

**Update**

Also, if I run the query used to check for extension version mismatch by the [extension update checking code in Postgres](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/pg__upgrade_8h.html#a6a11ba006bce453180b838813a7f581f)

```
SELECT name FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE installed_version != default_version;
```

With AWS RDS, I have permissions to connect to the databases `$mydatabase`, `postgres`, and `template1`. In doing so, all of them report 0 rows, i.e. no version mismatch. The other databases are `rdsadmin` and `template0` which I can't access. (I don't know if extensions are installed at the database or the cluster/installation level but I ran that query connected to each accessible database.)